# Should we answer questions where the OP has not shared their effort

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

...or has not shared what they have tried?

Too many times I see questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40633192/1011527) where no effort has been put forth to attempt a solution. This question received a couple of answers quickly, so it made me curious about how we should approach these.

- Is it sometimes more expedient to just answer the question, regardless of OP effort?
- Should "too broad" close votes be offered rapidly?
- Should we approach each question with a teaching mentality?

Comment: Showing no effort and not sharing what they have tried is distinct from overly broad.

Comment: *Is it sometimes more expedient to just answer the question, regardless of OP effort?* Opinion-based. Some of us refrain from doing that because they think it will encourage the questioner to keep on posting bad questions (I'm a member of this group). Others just answer everything that moves. To my knowledge there is no official consensus, and both sides are "right".

Comment: You're right @torazaburo, not enough coffee. I'll edit. But I do notice that many questions of this nature are often closed as too broad.

Comment: After a while, one gets used to how the flow goes and notice a particular pattern in "the flow". I have my own ways of dealing with this. I notice a low rep member (or 1 to 10 rep) I visit their profile and see if there are any other questions posted that either did not show any effort and/or have not accepted an answer where an obvious solution was given in order to mark the question as solved. If I feel that an/my answer should be posted in order to (hopefully) help someone else with a similar problem, then so be it; it's a judgement call (for me anyway). Edit: should this be an answer? lol

Comment: Only if, after you answer and they tell you "I already do that", you can murder them.